# How to handle orientation changes for home screen app widget?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Can anyone help me on how to handle orientation change for app widget?
On orientation change my widget is showing  layout with empty view and removing all listeners.

Comment: isn't it handled by the container of the appWidget, which asks to update it in case it's needed to? i think this question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14244949/878126 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9774228/878126

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After research and studying some of the folks answers , I came to know the mistake i have done.

After initial setup of the widget , I am again initializing remote views and trying to change only few views like when user taps on refresh button , iam making that view visibility gone and making circular progress loading view visibility visible and not again adding all other views and click listeners  i am updating the widget.

Appwidget manager will use last remote views object. So whenever orientation changes Appwidget manager is trying to load the latest remote view object by ignoring all the pending intent listeners and views.

I resolved this by creating remote view object with all my required view and listeners.

Comment: Yeah I had an initialise view and update view, as I thought the initialise view i.e. adding pending intents after every click was too heavy.  Unfortunately this is needed to handle orientation.